# Oracle ADF: Creating bar graph programmatically in 12c

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF, jDeveloper 12c. I have successfully created a bar graph programatically in jdeveloper 11.1.2.4 using [Creating Bar graph programatically](http://adfwithejb.blogspot.in/2013/01/programmatically-creation-of-bar-graph.html). Now am using 12c. I have searched a lot and got the information that in 12c only bar charts are there no bar graphs.

What ever there might be I need to create a bar graph programatically like below

[image]

please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally keep on trying I got the soluion with trail and error.

The following is the solution.

The following is the my model class

```
package org.abdul.view;

public class MyGraphModel {
    private Number value;
    private String group;

    public void setValue(Number value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyGraphModel(Number value, String group) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Number getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public MyGraphModel() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I have a page abc.jsf in that I have the following code

```
            <dvt:barChart id="chart1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_graphPage.chart1}"
                          value="#{backingBeanScope.backing_graphPage.value}"
                          var="row">
                <f:facet name="dataStamp">
                    <dvt:chartDataItem group="#{row.group}" id="cdi1"
                                       binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_graphPage.cdi1}"
                                       value="#{row.value}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </dvt:barChart>
```

in the backing bean of abc.jsf I have the following code.

```
private List<MyGraphModel> value;
public void setValue(List<MyGraphModel> value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public List<MyGraphModel> getValue() {
    value = new ArrayList<>();
    this.value.add(new MyGraphModel(10, "11"));
    this.value.add(new MyGraphModel(200, "1"));
    this.value.add(new MyGraphModel(30, "21"));
    this.value.add(new MyGraphModel(400, "2"));
    return value;
}
```

And the following is the output.

[image]